# Entity Framework - Conditionally adding columns into group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to conditionally add columns into GroupBy clause but I am not sure how it can be done.

I have 5 columns which I want to add in group by statement depending upon user's input. To do this I have following properties:

```
ProductId
ColorId
PieceId
SizeId
WeightId
```

If any property has value greater than 0 then this column needs to be used in group by clause.

So if ProductId, ColorId and PieceId has value greater than 0 than following should be there in group by:

```
list.GroupBy(p => new { p.Product.Id, p.ColorId, p.PieceId });
```

Comment: Perhaps, using `dynamic`? `.GroupBy(p => { dynamic exp = new ExpandoObject(); if (p.Product.Id > 0) exp.ProductId = p.Product.Id; /*other fields*/ return exp; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that;

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(p => new
{
    ProductId = p.Product.Id > 5 ? p.Product.Id : (int?)null,
    ColorId = p.ColorId > 5 ? p.ColorId : (int?)null,
    PieceId = p.PieceId > 5 ? p.PieceId : (int?)null
})
.Select(x =>
new
{
    x.Key.ProductId,
    x.Key.ColorId,
    x.Key.PieceId
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Suppose I have boolean variables instead of integer variables then what conditions do I need to place in group by?

Comment: You can perform same logic. Some thing like that; new
{
    Bool1 = p.Bool1 == true ? p.Bool1 : (bool?)null,
    Bool2= p.Bool2 == true ? p.Bool2 : (bool?)null,
    Bool3 = p.Bool3 == true ? p.Bool3 : (bool?)null,
}